# Need help understanding usage of ->, {} and () in this code

Tags: scala

Here is the piece of code in question:

```
val oauth_params = IMap(
      "oauth_consumer_key" -> consumer.key,
      "oauth_signature_method" -> "HMAC-SHA1",
      "oauth_timestamp" -> (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000).toString,
      "oauth_nonce" -> System.nanoTime.toString
    ) ++ token.map { "oauth_token" -> _.value } ++
      verifier.map { "oauth_verifier" -> _ }
```

**Question 1:** What Scala feature enabled `"oauth_consumer_key" -> consumer.key` to exist and passed as arguments?

**Question 2:** Seeing `val oauth_params = IMap(...)` and `token.map {...}`, which operations use `{}` for passing values rather than the usual `()`? Are there specific rules? And why is the `for` loop allowed to use both, if it is a related issue?

I ask here as I saw the features being used elsewhere. I also believe that both questions are related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order:

`->` is defined in `Predef.scala`, which is imported inside any other Scala source during the compilation:

```
final class ArrowAssoc[A](val x: A) {
  @inline def -> [B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = Tuple2(x, y)
  def →[B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = ->(y)
}
implicit def any2ArrowAssoc[A](x: A): ArrowAssoc[A] = new ArrowAssoc(x)
```

**As you can see, there is an implicit conversion that convert any object into an ArrowAssoc[A], which has a method ->[B] which returns a Tuple2[A,B].**

IMap(...) it's the call to the method IMap.apply(...) : in Scala if a method is named apply, you can omit it. In this case, it is used as a factory method in a very common pattern in Scala

```
class MyClass(....) {

}
object MyClass{ 
   def apply(....): MyClass = new MyClass(....)
}

val a = MyClass(a,b,c)
```

**What you just saw is a Scala class and its companion object: a singleton which has to be defined in the same source file as the class and which can also access private and protected fields in the the class itself**

The map function receives a function which takes the same type of the collection and returns a different type. Example: `List(1,2,3).map ( x => x * 2)`. ( ) and { } are interchangeable in Scala excepts with the case construct.

Comment: `_` works just as well with `()`. It’s only when you want to use `case` or multiple expressions that you have to wrap it in a `{}` block.

Comment: That last part is incorrect.  `List(1,2,3).map(_*2)` is valid, at least in scala 2.9.2.  iirc, you can use `{}` in place of `()` any time there's only a single parameter.

Comment: They're not actually interchangeable (e.g. `List{1,2,3}` does not work); it's just that `()` can be omitted where the argument is a function literal, and the `{}` around a function literal can be omitted when enclosed by `()`. Pattern matches using `case` must always be surrounded by `{}`.

Comment: The case about () and {} is actually much more complex. () can be replaced by {} when it's around an expression. Parameter lists with multiple parameters, `if`/`while`, declarations and who knows what else do not qualify. {} can only be replaced by () if it contains a single statement, and that statement is an expression (instead of a declaration).